# Is there a way to search venues by price using the Foursquare API?

Tags: ios, swift, foursquare, swifty-json

I'm creating an iOS project in Swift using the Foursquare API [this API](https://github.com/koogawa/FoursquareAPIClient), and SwiftyJSON. Is there any way to get Venue results that match a certain price tier?

I understand how to receive venue results including the price tier, but, aside from checking the price tier and filtering out the relevant ones, I'm not sure how to receive venues only matching a certain price tier.

EDIT:
My current code looks like this:

```
 func setUpFoursquare(){
    let client = FoursquareAPIClient(clientId: "JMBLK0SDZ0N2NF5TG3UCLMOF4FA5FKA14AIOZ4P4TS4MHEWO", clientSecret: "*****")

    let parameter: [String: String] = [
        "near": "Toronto",//destination!,
        "limit": "4",
        "query": "sushi",
        "price": "1",
        ];
    print("Parameter: \(parameter)");
    print("client: \(client)");
    //The path is based on the request link. For example, the request link for photos is:
    //GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/photos
    //So the path would correspond tovenues/VENUE_ID/photos where VENUE_ID is the corresponding ID.
    client.request(path: "venues/search", parameter: parameter) { result in
        //        client.request(path: "venues/categories", parameter: parameter) { result in

        switch result {
        case let .success(data):
            print("Success")
            guard let json = try? JSON(data: data) else{
                print("\(#function): Unable to retrieve json object")
                return
            }
            print("Json: \(json)")
            if json["meta"]["code"] == 200{
                self.parse(jsonObject: json)
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            // Error handling
            switch error {
            case let .connectionError(connectionError):
                print(connectionError)
            case let .responseParseError(responseParseError):
                print(responseParseError)   // e.g. JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
            case let .apiError(apiError):
                print(apiError.errorType)   // e.g. endpoint_error
                print(apiError.errorDetail) // e.g. The requested path does not exist.
            }
        }//end switch
    }//end client.request


}
```

However the "price":"1" parameter doesn't actually alter the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `venues/explore` endpoint you can filter results by price tiers. See the documentation here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/explore

Specifically, you will need to use the `price` parameter:

> Comma separated list of price points. Currently the valid range of
>   price points are [1,2,3,4], 1 being the least expensive, 4 being the
>   most expensive. For food venues, in the United States, 1 is < $10 an
>   entree, 2 is $10-$20 an entree, 3 is $20-$30 an entree, 4 is > $30 an
>   entree.

Using the API wrapper you linked to, that would look something like this...

```
let parameter: [String: String] = [
    "ll": "35.702069,139.7753269",
    "limit": "10",
    "price": "1,2"
];

client.request(path: "venues/explore", parameter: parameter) { result in
    // do your SwiftyJSON stuff
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, however it did not return different results. Using the parameters "near" : "New York", "limit" : "4",  "query" : "sushi", "price":"1" returned the same results as when I changed the price to 4.

Comment: Never mind, it was because I was using the path "venues/search" rather than "venues/explore". Thanks.